# Change domain from example.com/48 to example.com Wordpress Ec2 AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, cross-domain

I had problems when I copy and pasted my wordpress files in /var/www/html/ from /var/www/html/48 where I extracted my wordpress file to.

The result I am seeking is to have 48n.ca redirect to 48n.ca/48/

Thank you

Comment: deleted and reinstalled I think i had changed config too many times not knowing what I was doing, steps are here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

Please [read the docs on migrating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_Directories_On_Your_Existing_Server).

**Short answer:** you can't just copy and paste your files to a new directory and expect it to work.

In addition, you need to [change your site and WordPress URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database) in the `wp_options` database table and re-save permalinks (among other things). This is the primary reason you're seeing the redirect. WordPress still thinks your site should be in the original directory, because you haven't updated any database values.

Comment: I think I had changed my config files too often so I did a reinstall following these steps http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html